# Search Plus Custom Mapping

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-searchplus

I've not managed to find any complete example of a custom mapping plugin for Search Plus—I'm wondering if anyone could steer me in the right direction?

In a nutshell what I'm wanting to do is to modify the standard Search Plus mapping to include the `section handle`. I think this is the function I need:

```
public function searchPlus_alterBasicItemMapping($mappedData, $orginalElement)
{
    $mappedData["sectionHandle"] = $section->handle;
    return $mappedData;
}
```

But I have no idea where to put it and how to get it to talk to the plugin...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A while since you asked, so in case you haven't figured it out yet, here goes:

To attach to a plugin hook, you need to create your own plugin. So in your plugins folder, add a new folder called `SearchPlusItemMapping` or whatever you want to call your plugin. In that folder you'll need to create a php file called `SearchPlusItemMappingPlugin` (change whatever comes before `Plugin` if you gave your plugin a different name. In this file, add the following lines:
    namespace Craft;

```
class SearchPlusMappingPlugin extends BasePlugin
{
    public function getName()
    {
        return Craft::t('Search Plus Item Mapping');
    }

    public function getVersion()
    {
        return '1.0';
    }

    public function getDeveloper()
    {
        return 'Your Name';
    }

    public function getDeveloperUrl()
    {
        return 'https://somesite.com';
    }

    public function searchPlus_alterBasicItemMapping(){}
}
```

And then at the bottom you add your function.